# Django. Related model returns None after primary model save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have two models: `Item` and `Photo`. `Item` is foreignkey to `Photo` so one item can have many photos connected which is quite usual.

Item class:

```
class Item(models.Model):
name = models.CharField('Item Name',
    max_length = 150,
    null = False,
    blank = False
)
description = RichTextField('Item Description')
```

Photo class:

```
class Photo(models.Model):

path_and_rename = PathAndRename()

photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = path_and_rename, blank = True, null = True)
item = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name = 'photo_set')
```

When I'm creating new `Item` entry with bunch of photos I'd like to do some additional stuff: launching asynchronous task for indexing and email notification of user - `some_async_task()`. I'm trying to do it by `Item.save()` method:

```
    def save(self):
    super(Item, self).save()

    some_async_task.delay(self.id)


@task(name="something")
def something(item_id):
    print Item.objects.get(pk=item_id).photo_set.first().photo.url
```

It seems `save()` method of Item model is exactly what I need but problem is that even after calling `super()` I can't get data about related Photo entries because such relationship doesn't exist.

What is the best way to run method after Item entry was created and all related Photo entries were related?

`post_save` signal doesn't fix situation.

Comment: Please post parts of your code

Comment: sorry. have no access to console now so can't paste error code. will update later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Item` is the main model and the photos are related, this means that when `Item` is saved it does not necessarily have the relations to the photos, yet.

To know when this has happened:
"to run method after Item entry was created and all related Photo entries were related"
is something that depends on your business logic.

Do you know in your view when exactly all of the photos have been added?

If yes: then call the task then and there, in your view code.

If no:

- either override `Photo.save()` (calling the task after every new photo)
- or in your current task code, add a check whether there are any photos, yet (that is probably something worth adding in any case)
- use a signal handler (`post_save`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) instead of overriding `save()`

Comment: Thanks Risadinha. I was using `post_save` signal actually on `Item` object. Results were the same. So it seems that it's better to tweak `Photo.save()` method or bind `post_save` signal to `Photo` and run task with every photo update. Also I did put `sleep(10)` function at top of async task so at moment actual query is being passed to database all entries are updated and relations are saved. And it works. But I still don't like such approach.

Comment: After thinking a bit more (which is always neccessary :) it became clear that such logic should go only into view. Putting everything into model and chaining signals is bad idea. Only the view has full contol over flow of related models so everythong I need is just put call to my async tasks into view after `item.save()` code.